# Pandasでmode()の結果のみをfor文で取得する方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下のコードを実行した結果、最頻値をseries型で取得できたのですが、「大字仲原」や「大字鉄輪」など実際のデータだけを取得するためにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

▼コード

```
null_stationAreas = df["地区名"].isnull()
for null_stationArea in list(df.loc[null_stationAreas,"最寄駅：名称"].unique()):
    mode = df.loc[(~null_stationAreas) & (df["最寄駅：名称"]==null_stationArea),"地区名"].mode()
    print(mode)
```

▼実行結果一部抜粋

```
0    大字仲原
dtype: object
Series([], dtype: object)
0    大字鉄輪
dtype: object
0    大字南立石
1      石垣東
dtype: object
0    本町
dtype: object
0    徳倉
1     萩
dtype: object
0    水戸島本町
dtype: object
```

▼試したこと
Series型なのでほしいデータのインデックス番号である０を指定しました。最初のデータである「大字仲原」は取得できましたが他の「大字鉄輪」などは取得できずエラーが表示されデータを取得できませんでした。
エラーについてはスクリーンショットをご参照ください。

```
null_stationAreas = df["地区名"].isnull()
for null_stationArea in list(df.loc[null_stationAreas,"最寄駅：名称"].unique()):
    mode = df.loc[(~null_stationAreas) & (df["最寄駅：名称"]==null_stationArea),"地区名"].mode()[0]
    print(mode)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

`values` を使います。

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

data_csv = '''
地区名,最寄駅：名称
,A
,B
,C
,C
大字仲原,A
大字仲原,A
大字仲原,B
大字仲原,C
大字鉄輪,A
大字鉄輪,B
大字鉄輪,B
大字鉄輪,C
大字鉄輪,C
大字南立石,A
大字南立石,B
大字南立石,C
大字南立石,C
大字南立石,D
大字南立石,D
'''.strip()

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_csv))

null_stationAreas = df["地区名"].isnull()
for null_stationArea in list(df.loc[null_stationAreas,"最寄駅：名称"].unique()):
    mode = df.loc[
               (~null_stationAreas) & (df["最寄駅：名称"]==null_stationArea), "地区名"
           ].mode().values
    print(mode)

#
['大字仲原']
['大字鉄輪']
['大字南立石' '大字鉄輪']
```

また、以下の様にも書くことができます(結果はデータフレーム)。

```py
stations = df.loc[df['地区名'].isnull(), "最寄駅：名称"].unique()
dfx = (
  df.dropna()
    .loc[df["最寄駅：名称"].isin(stations)]
    .groupby("最寄駅：名称")
    .apply(lambda x: x["地区名"].mode().values)
    .to_frame("地区名(最頻値)"))

print(dfx)
#
                      地区名(最頻値)
最寄駅：名称                        
A                         [大字仲原]
B                         [大字鉄輪]
C             [大字南立石, 大字鉄輪]
```

Comment: metropolisさん
ありがとうございます。同頻度のものがあれば最初のものだけを文字列として取得したかった為、valuesで取得したあとにlist(mode)[0]　とすることでやりたいことが実現できました。